# How to print a string before line N and delete specific string from line N using AWK or SED

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have an text file consisting of HTML code that I need to manipulate to become more readable. My problem is that I have two lines of each file name that are not unique, but I need to distinguish them apart:

*EDIT*

I'll put the input here for those who asked for it:

```
<body>
<tbody>
<tr><td><b>Test Suite</b></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="HAPPY/3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY">3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="HAPPY/fullform_no_prefill_HAPPY">fullform_no_prefill_HAPPY</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="HAPPY/fullform_mobile_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY">fullform_mobile_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="SAD/3_step_minimal_foundation_SAD">3_step_minimal_foundation_SAD</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="SAD/fullform_SAD">fullform_SAD</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="SAD/fullform_mobile_foundation_SAD">fullform_mobile_foundation_SAD</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS/3_step_minimal_foundation_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS">3_step_minimal_foundation_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS/fullform_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS">fullform_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS/fullform_mobile_foundation_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS">fullform_mobile_foundation_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS/3_step_minimal_foundation_SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS">3_step_minimal_foundation_SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS/fullform_SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS">fullform_SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS/fullform_mobile_foundation_SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS">fullform_mobile_foundation_SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
```

3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY

and

3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY

for example needs to become:

3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill

and

3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY

My current state of the text file:

this is the code I have that achieves this:

```
$ sed -n '/ref/p' EVERYTHING | awk -F'[/"<> ]+' '{sub("", "", $6); print $6, $7, $8}' | tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' | awk -v n=3 '1; NR % n == 0 {print ""}' | sed '/^HAPPY/s/^/Flow Type\: /' | sed '/^SAD/s/^/Flow Type\: /' | sed '$d'

Flow Type: HAPPY
3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY
3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY

Flow Type: HAPPY
fullform_no_prefill_HAPPY
fullform_no_prefill_HAPPY

Flow Type: HAPPY
fullform_mobile_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY
fullform_mobile_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY

Flow Type: SAD
3_step_minimal_foundation_SAD
3_step_minimal_foundation_SAD

Flow Type: SAD
fullform_SAD
fullform_SAD

Flow Type: SAD
fullform_mobile_foundation_SAD
fullform_mobile_foundation_SAD

Flow Type: HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS
3_step_minimal_foundation_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS
3_step_minimal_foundation_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS

Flow Type: HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS
fullform_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS
fullform_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS
```

My desired output:

```
Flow Type: HAPPY
Flow Name: 3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill
File Name: 3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY

Flow Type: HAPPY
Flow Name: fullform_no_prefill
File Name: fullform_no_prefill_HAPPY

Flow Type: HAPPY
Flow Name: fullform_mobile_foundation_no_prefill
File Name: fullform_mobile_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY

Flow Type: SAD
Flow Name: 3_step_minimal_foundation
File Name: 3_step_minimal_foundation_SAD

Flow Type: SAD
Flow Name: fullform
File Name: fullform_SAD

Flow Type: SAD
Flow Name: fullform_mobile_foundation
File Name: fullform_mobile_foundation_SAD

Flow Type: HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS
Flow Name: 3_step_minimal_foundation
File Name: 3_step_minimal_foundation_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS

Flow Type: HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS
Flow Name: fullform
File Name: fullform_HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS
```

Is there a way to maybe delete/keep specific text from line numbered N? Once I get each line unique, it will be easy enough to correctly label each line.

-Best

Comment: Which lines are you trying to remove here? Currently it's unclear. It's good that you're trying to split the problem up into steps but perhaps it would be easier to go directly from the input to the output.

Comment: I'm not trying to remove any lines, I'm trying to distinguish the two lines that are not unique for each file i.e. (3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY and
3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY) I need to take off the _HAPPY for one of those lines and leave the other the same.

Comment: I can add the input if that would make it easier *EDIT* ok, input is there to view now. Appreciate all the help so far!

Comment: Well, it's certainly not easy now, so go for it, add anything you can.  Example input and intended output are the standards, along with any code that you've already written that attempts to achieve what you're doing. If you can explain how you think the code should work, then the process of solving the problem will be MUCH faster.

Comment: Would it be safe to say that you want to remove everything from the last underscore to the end of the line, for lines that match the previous line?

Comment: I'll also add my current code *EDIT* Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, for the basic functionality of removing everything from the underscore to the end of the line for lines that match the previous line, the process is pretty easy.  Here are two options, 100% un-tested.

In awk:

```
awk '$0 == last { sub(/_[^_]+$/,""); } { last=$0; } 1' inputfile
```

In shell:

```
while read line; do
    if [ "$line" = "$last" ]; then
        line="${line%_*}"
    fi
    echo "$line"
    last="$line"
done < inputfile
```

But this changes the *second* of the two lines.  For the additional formatting you need, it looks like you want to modify the *first* of the two lines.  This makes this just a little more complex...

To go from the text that you have to the text that you want, let's look at this a different way, and assume that the two repeated lines *always* appear after a line starting with "Flow Type:".

```
awk '
  /^Flow Type:/ {
    print;
    getline one; getline two
    if (one == two) {
      sub(/_[^_]+$/,"",one);
      print "Flow Name: " one;
      print "File Name: " two;
    } else {
      print one; print two
    }
    next;
  }

  1
' inputfile
```

But we could also just process your original HTML.

In sed, pattern recognition is super fun.  Here's one in GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's|<tr><td><a href="([^/]+)/(([^"]+)_[^_]+)".*|Flow Type: \1\nFlow Name: \3\nFile Name: \2|' input.html
```

It's the newlines (`\n`) that require GNU sed in this; structurally it's just plain sed.  This solution won't work in *BSD or OSX.

> **EDIT**: Per comments on potong's answer, a variation that would work in OSX would be this:
>
> ```
> <input.html sed -n 's/^.*"\([^"\/]*\)\/\(\([^"]*\)_\1\)".*/Flow Type: \1|Flow Name: \3|File Name: \2|/p'  | tr '|' '\n'`
> ```
>
> or if you prefer ERE instead of BRE:
>
> ```
> <input.html sed -E 's|<tr><td><a href="([^/]+)/(([^"]+)_[^_]+)".*|Flow Type: \1#Flow Name: \3#File Name: \2#|' | tr '#' '\n'
> ```

This addresses the limitation that OSX sed is unable to insert newlines into the replacement string of a **s**ubstitute. Instead, we insert an otherwise unused character, and use `tr` to convert it to a newline.

To achieve the same goal in awk (i.e. process the HTML), you might go with something like this:

```
awk '
  /<tr><td><a/ {

    type=$0; file=$0;
    sub(/^[^"]+/,"",type); sub(/\/.*/,"",type);
    sub(/^[^\/]+\//,"",file); sub(/".*/,"",file);
    name=file; sub(/_[^_]+$/,"",name);

    printf("Flow type: %s\nFlow name: %s\nFile name: %s\n\n", type, name, file);

  }' input.html
```

---

Okay, this is my last update.  Is this what you are looking for?

```
awk '
  /<tr><td><a/ {

    type=$0; sub(/^[^"]+"/,"",type); sub(/\/.*/,"",type);
    file=$0; sub(/^[^\/]+\//,"",file); sub(/".*/,"",file);

    if ( index(file, type) ) {
        name=substr(file, 0, index(file, type)-2);
    } else {
        name=file; sub(/_[^_]+$/,"",name);
    }

    printf("Flow type: %s\nFlow name: %s\nFile name: %s\n\n", type, name, file);

  }'
```

Comment: I apologize, It seems I informed you with slightly incorrect information. I meant to say that it's safe to assume that I need the text that comes after the HAPPY/SAD/HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS/SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS for the flow name as presented in the desired output above. Really sorry about that. Although, this does work with what you said. Thank you for that!

Is there a way that I can cut off a specific string from every 3rd line BEFORE I pipe in the extra spacing between each file set? and after that is done THEN pipe the extra lines between each set back in?

Comment: This ends up getting rid of the Flow Type: lines. Is there a small change that can be made that keeps these in tact?

Comment: I'm getting an illegal option -- r with that command. Am I missing a module to be able to use this? I'm fairly new to SED and AWK so I apologize. Really appreciate all this help!

Comment: Ah, are you using OSX, or a BSD based operating system?  If so, try replacing `-r` with `-E`.  Newer BSD added `-r` for compatibility with GNU sed, but in OSX and older variants `-E` should achieve the same thing.

Comment: I'm using OSX. Tried out the SED solution you had above, the files containing HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS/SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS still have the HAPPY_PLUS/SAD_PLUS at the end. Is there a way to select this string from those specific lines that require it and delete them for their Flow Names?

Comment: Also, with that last AWK solution, I'm getting this error:

`awk: extra ] at source line 6
 context is
     >>>  sub(/^[^/] <<< 
awk: nonterminated character class ^[^
 source line number 6`

Comment: Ah, right, OSX does not use GNU sed, so while you can recognize ERE using the `-E` option, it still won't handle `\n` properly. For the awk solution, it seems like the forward slash inside the range (square brackets) needs to be escaped.  I've updated the answer and tested it this time. :)

Comment: This is still not getting rid of the HAPPY_PLUS/SAD_PLUS from that last 8 files for the Flow Name's. Also, It doesn't look like it's cutting out the first " from the Flow Types for each one. Any ideas on how to change this? So close!

Comment: Okay, so if your flow type has underscores in it, the idea of removing "from the underscore to the end" no longer works.  That's a solvable programming problem, but I tell you what, how about YOU try to write some code for it, and I'll help you debug it. :-)

Comment: Added one more option. Please test with your input data.

Comment: Yes! that is a lot better than my solution that I just posted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

awk to the rescue

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"; h="\nFile Name: "}{gsub("_"$3,"",$4); $4=h$4; $5=h$5"\n"; print}'
```

with an extra empty line at the end.  If important you can trim it with some extra logic, or simply piping the output to `sed '$d'`, or `head -n -1`

revised version with comments (thx to Tom Fenech)

```
awk -vRS= '{                        # set awk to paragraph mode 
       sub("_" $3, "", $4)          # remove name from field suffix
       $4 = "\nFlow Name: " $4      # construct new fields with header and newline  
       $5 = "\nFile Name: " $5 "\n" # extra new line for record separation
       print                        # print all fields
    }'
```

There is not much to it.  You define the record as the full block of text, instead of each line (this solves half of the problem). Based on your format we can refer to individual fields by their index.  Remove suffix from one field defined as another field and prepare other fields with headers.

Comment: Instead of adding the newline to `$5`, I would suggest using a block at the start `NR>1{ print "" }`. You can also use `sub` instead of `gsub` and possibly should consider adding an anchor to the end of the field `"_"$3"$"`. Also, note that the prefix for the second line is different to that for the third of each block. Finally, you can use `awk -v RS=` to read each block one at a time (so you can get rid of the `BEGIN` block).

Comment: I'm not really sure what this is doing. Care to explain it briefly? I tried implementing it and it's returning an odd format. There are new lines for the file name: , but there are two of them and the actual flow name and file name are not on those lines.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr 's/^.*"([^"\/]*)\/(([^"]*)_\1)".*/Flow Type: \1\nFlow Name: \3\nFile Name: \2\n/p' file
```

Use extended regexp and do not automatically print every line. Match on the required string and use backreferences to extract the required output. Print only on successful substitution.

An alternative solution that might work on other sed's:

```
sed -n -e 'G' -e 's/^.*"\([^"\/]*\)\/\(\([^"]*\)_\1\)".*\(.\)/Flow Type: \1\4Flow Name: \3\4File Name: \2\4/p' file
```

Comment: That's similar to the sed solution I came up with, but as he stated in comments to my answer, he's on OSX and not using GNU sed.

Comment: Hmm.  Not quite. When you say `$"\n"` do you really mean to use bash's special quoting, like `$'\n'`? If so, that adds a separate dependency. I'd love to see something that uses the hold space to assemble lines, but it might be easier just to use `tr`.  Something like this:  `< file sed -n 's/^.*"\([^"\/]*\)\/\(\([^"]*\)_\1\)".*/Flow Type: \1|Flow Name: \3|File Name: \2|/p'  | tr '|' '\n'`

Comment: @ghoti see final amendment to alternative.

Comment: THAT'S what I'm talking about.  Your sed-fu is strong.  :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  /<tr><td><a/ {

    type=$0; file=$0;
    sub(/^[^S|^H]+/,"",type); sub(/\/.*/,"",type);
    sub(/^[^\/]+\//,"",file); sub(/".*/,"",file);
    name=file; sub(/_[^fullform|^prefill]+$/,"",name);

    printf("Flow type: %s\nFlow name: %s\nFile name: %s\n\n", type, name, file);

  }’ Filename.txt
```

This is what I've come up with for my solution. It works for what I need. I ended up specifying the actual strings to cut off at, which is fine for now. In the future I will improve this solution to make it more forward compatible. Thanks everyone for all your help!